# Separated Authorship by Affiliation

Tags: titles, affiliation

I need to make my paper look exactly like this, but I'm not sure of the syntax to do it. It's certainly not standard format. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `authblk`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}               %% for roman text
\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}         % The option is for block layout
\renewcommand\Authfont{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\affilsep}{0.1em}

\title{Title}

\author{First author\thanks{Job here}\,\,}
\author{Second author\thanks{Job there} }
\affil{Department 1 \\
School 1 \\
}

\author{Third author\thanks{Job elsehere} }
\affil{Department 2 \\
School 2 \\
}

\author{and\\[1em]Fourth author\thanks{Job here} }
\affil{Department 3 \\
School 3 \\
}

\date{}

%% needed as you want numbers, otherwise \maketitle uses symbols
\makeatletter
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or 1\or 2\or 3\or
   4\or 5\or 6\or 7\or 8
   \or 9 \else 10\fi}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With affilliation coming directly under the names, the foot note marks are redundant IMO.

Comment: Thanks! The footnotes have the authors' job titles, it's a silly layout (their entire paper template is absurd), but I don't get much say in the matter if I want to be in the conference.

Comment: @Jordan Answer edited. Hope it is Ok.